# preventDefault not working in Google Chrome 5

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I want to stop a form submit button from reloading a page. This works in Firefox 3.6, Safari 5, and Opera. But Chrome 5 does not prevent the link.

Here is the form.

```
<form class="container_7" id="find-store-all" action=" ">
 <label for="customer-loc" class="grid_3">Find a Store Near You:</label>
 <input name="customer-loc" id="customer-loc" class="grid_3" type="text" placeholder="zip code or address"  />
    <button type="submit" id="customer-loc-sub" class="grid_1" >Enter</button>
</form>
```

I am using event delegation to manage the click. Here is the JavaScript.

```
document.onclick = handleClick;

function handleClick(e){
 if(!e) var e = window.event; 
 var target = e.target || e.srcElement;

 switch(target.id){
  case "customer-loc-sub" :
  e.preventDefault();
  findClosestStoreOne();
  break;
 }

}
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried debugging it yet? Have you alerted what the id is? Have you alerted and confirmed there is an event object being passed and it contains those properties?

Comment: Yes. The event object is passed. And the script works as expected in Firefox, Safari, and Opera.

What's more, if I place the listener on an element that does not have a default behavior, for example, a span, the script runs in Chrome. It seems only not to work when I need to prevent the default action from a from submission.

Comment: Seems to be working here: http://jsfiddle.net/vgHMt/ (Chrome 5.0.375.127). Try it, and then try it with `e.preventDefault()` commented out.

Comment: Ryan, for me it is not working at jsfiddle.net. The alert is not showing up. I am also using Chrome 5.0.375.127.  Makes me wonder if this is a Chrome setting.

Comment: Well that *is* odd. Sounds like it could be a Chrome setting indeed.

Comment: Any thoughts on what I might be? I am using vanilla Chrome with no extensions.

Answer (score 5):

`preventDefault()` isn't the best way to prevent the browser's default behaviour in this type of DOM 0 event handler, as it certainly doesn't work in IE and possibly other browsers too. Just use `return false;` instead. Works in all browsers.

```
document.onclick = handleClick;

function handleClick(e){
 if(!e) var e = window.event; 
 var target = e.target || e.srcElement;

 switch(target.id){
  case "customer-loc-sub" :
  findClosestStoreOne();
  return false;
 }
}
```

Comment: Tim, thanks. But return false, doesn't work either. I tried "return false," "e.returnValue = false," and I placed return false in a separate function.

Comment: This works for me in Chrome 5: the form does not submit. Are you sure there's no error in `findClosestStoreOne();`?

Comment: Tim, thanks. I found the issue. I had another event that was affecting this. I modified the other event, and both preventDefault() and return false are working now. Thanks for your suggestions. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this. There are another event (the entire script is about 900 lines) that was affecting this. Thanks for your help. Especially Ryan Kinal. His comment's got me to look at the problem from another angle...so to speak.