# HTML5 Audio control Issue in Chrome

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome, html5-audio

When we bind "mouseup" event to document and have preventDefault for it. The slider element is moving continously we are unable to stop it. i have herewith attached a fiddler for checking

```
 <div id="audioPlayer">
        <audio controls>
            <source src="http://www.grupobms.com/MaterialFiles/Ford2013.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">

            Your browser does not support the audio element.
        </audio>
    </div>

$(document).bind("mouseup", function (e) {

           e.preventDefault();

           });
```

1. Open this link in chrome browser

http://jsfiddle.net/W2R2G/

1. Click on slide element and move it and try to stop it.

Comment: I am using chrome 31 and no issue with me. Working f9 for me.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure where is the problem but if I simply remove prevent default everything is working fine in [Chrome](http://jsfiddle.net/W2R2G/2/).

```
$(document).bind("mouseup", function (e) {
           console.log(".");
});
```

Comment: But here i need preventDefault in my scenario so only checking for solution.

Comment: Why do you need it? It's working exactly as intended by sticking to the volume slider.

Comment: @ Jamie I am custom control developer and in my custom control mouseup event for document i need to use preventDefault. Consider a scenario where default action needs to be prevented and i need to do some processing.

Comment: Well, you are preventing the default action, which would be the mouseUp event bubbling through to the audio control.

Comment: I am not recommending you preventsDefault please read here more http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558537/preventdefault-not-working-in-google-chrome-5 and here http://bolsterweb.com/2011/01/javascript-e-preventdefault-is-not-return-false/. and finally here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18389046/event-preventdefault-does-not-work-in-chrome-and-opera

Comment: @Jamie e.stopPropagation is used to stop the bubbling whereas i stopped the default event only.

Comment: My mistake, but if the default action is to lose focus of the volume slider and you're preventing that, that's why you're having issues now.

Answer (score 0):

If not preventing default action of audio player, every things fine for me. Hope this may help.

```
$(document).bind("mouseup", function (e) {
    if(e.target.nodeName != 'AUDIO') {
       e.preventDefault();
    } });
```